# how to pass dynamic contents to mandrill Template in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, mandrill

have created a template over my mandril account: 
order_confirmation

```
<div class="thank-you">
        Thank you for your <b> *|ORDER|* </b> order !
</div>

<div class="thank-you">
Please find Summary of your order   <span class="order-no"> *|ORDER|* </span>  from below section. 
</div>
```

i have written below code to pass dynamic values for ORDER & ORDER_NUMBER

```
m =Mandrill.new "API KEY"

template_name = "order_confirmation"

template_content = [{"name"=>"example name", "content"=>"example content"}]

message = {  

  "subject" => "Order Confirmation message",  
  "from_name" => "Application",  
 :text=>"Order Confirmation Message",  
 :to=>[  
   {  
     :email=> "rec@email.com",  
     :name=> "recipient name"  
   }  
 ],
"merge"=>true,
"global_merge_vars" =>[
 {
    "ORDER" => "577575"
 }
],
 :from_email=>"sender@yourdomain.com"  
}  

sending = m.messages.send message
```

its able to send mail but my template contents  are not rendered in the mail content.

Comment: Set Merge Tag data first using this API request

http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/merge-var-set.php

Comment: <div>example code</div>

Dear *|USER|*,
   Thank you for your purchase on *|ORDER|* from ABC Widget Company. 
We appreciate your business and have included a copy of your invoice below.

have already included this content in my template.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the name in the ruby code is lower case.

So if it's

```
*|ORDER|*
```

Then in your code it should be:

```
template_content = [{"name"=>"order", "content"=>"example content"}]
```

Comment: in my case it also working even name key having caps latters like : ORDER